# Generating random number 1 - 100 in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2

I was wondering if this is the best way to generate a random number in Swift.

This is what I have thought of thus far:

```
var randomNumber:Int = random() * 100 + 1 //What value does this return?
```

I was wondering if this is a viable 1 - 100 range in Swift utilizing the random() function? I am unsure if this is. I have not dealt with random numbers much in Swift 2. However in Java, the equivalent would be `Math.random() * 100 + 1`

I'm curious to know what would be the equivalent of this in Swift 2. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EricD. yes, I flagged it but it didn't auto-generate the comment for some reason

Comment: @originaluser2 I think it doesn't when it detects a comment with the link already in it, and there was one at this moment.

Answer (score -1):

```
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)
```

+ 1 since `arc4random_uniform` generates a random number between 0 and the parameter - 1

Comment: really? do we need 2 virtually identical answers on a question that's a duplicate anyway?

Comment: Are you sure this still works in the latest iteration of XCode and Swift? I do not see this option anymore in Xcode.

Comment: @Linuxn00b you have to import the `Darwin` module (as stated in the duplicate question)

Comment: @originaluser2 it seems to work without the Darwin module. Thanks for all your help.